# Getting XML into SQL server column

Tags: xml

I am trying to put the entire XML into one column in a SQL server table but I keep getting the following error

[SQL Server]XML parsing: line 0, character 0, unrecognized input signature

In my table I have set the XML column to datatype XML

This is my code below.

```
  ALTER Procedure [dbo].[PopulateGECH_ICU_DataTable]
  @HospitalNumber VARCHAR(20),
  @CaseID VARCHAR(20),
  @SpellID VARCHAR(20),
  @XML XML,
  @ProcessFlag VARCHAR(5),
  
  @LogComment VARCHAR (100) OUTPUT,
  @Alert INT OUTPUT

  


AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRAN  

        SET @LogComment = 'No Log Comment'
        SET @Alert = 0 
        
        
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO test.GE_Table(HospitalNumber,CaseNumber,SpellId,XML,UserCreate,CreateDateTime,UserModifed,ModifiedDateTime,Processed)
        VALUES (@HospitalNumber,@CaseID, @SpellID, @XML, 'Service' , GETDATE(), 'Service' , GETDATE(), @ProcessFlag)
        
        SET @LogComment = 'Process Flag Updated'
        
        END
    
    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN 99
    END 
        
    COMMIT TRAN
END
```

The data/XML I am trying to insert which is set to @XML is

```
<TEST xmlns='http://tempuri.org/ICMPDSv3_1.xsd'><ADMISSION><identifier>ZX000</identifier><ACON>U</ACON><ACSD>0</ACSD><WKG>80</WKG><WKGEST>1</WKGEST></ADMISSION></TEST>
```

Comment: XML must start with an open angle bracket.  The data you are trying to insert do not start with the anglebracket.

Comment: You have too many closing brackets at the end of your XML declaration, and need a space between "TEST" and "xmlns".